# page is not rendering again on react-router-dom V4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router-dom v4.
Here is my router code snippet.

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, BroswserHistory} from 'react-router-dom';
<Router>
<Main>
<route exact path="/" component={All}/>
...
<route path="/user/:id" component={User}/>
</Main>
</Router>
```

So when go to **/user/123** I can get user page but if go to **/user/345** on the same page, in other words, when redirect to another link which has only new user id, I can't get new user page only it's keeping previous page.

What is wrong with me?

Comment: Wrap your component with 'withRouter' of react-router-dom and try. Like `export default withRouter(YourComponent)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you navigate to same route path , react will not render again 
U can do below my suggestion :

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextState) {
    if (this.state.path != nextProps.location.pathname) {
        this.setState({
            path: nextProps.location.pathname
        }, () => {
            //process with your parameter here
        })
    }
}
```